# How to get lengths between intersecting points

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have a route that goes all the way along the project scope (Route A) and then multiple other alternative routes that intersect Route A at different points ([See picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwNsL.jpg)).  I want to get the lengths that Route A is between the alternative routes.  I've exported the routes previously but it was only for the individual lengths themselves.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Images should always be embedded in the question, since external links are rarely followed, and can go stale, damaging question quality.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: First, create a road graph of your road model ...